# Issues defining setCommandCB function for a 7 joint robot torque control

Tags: gazebo-plugin, ros-control, ros-noetic, gazebo-ros-control

I'm writing my own effort controller based in a simple example from gazebo webpage to test it in a robot and I'm having an issue when writing `void setCommandCB` function.

So far I managed myself to write the code for a 7DOF robot but I'm stuck in this fucntion as I dont quite understand what does this function exactly. I guess that is the callback that is called whenever receives the messages from the command topic right?

maybe my code approach is wrong, I just want to control each of the joints of the robot sending a torque command to them.

```
#include <controller_interface/controller.h>
#include <hardware_interface/joint_command_interface.h>
#include <pluginlib/class_list_macros.h>
#include <std_msgs/Float64.h>

namespace panda_torque_control {


class ImpedanceController : public controller_interface::Controller<hardware_interface::EffortJointInterface> {

private:
  std::vector<hardware_interface::JointHandle> joints_;
  ros::Subscriber sub_command_;
  std::vector<double> tauCommand;
  

public:
  bool init(hardware_interface::EffortJointInterface *hw, ros::NodeHandle &n) {
    std::vector<std::string> joint_names;
    if (!n.getParam("joint_names", joint_names)) 
    {
        ROS_ERROR("Could not find joint names");
        return false;

    }

    // Initialize joint handles for each joint
    for (const auto &joint_name : joint_names) {
      joints_.push_back(hw->getHandle(joint_name));
    } // throws on failure
    
    tauCommand = {0,0,0,0,0,0,0};


    // Start command subscriber
    sub_command_ = n.subscribe<std_msgs::Float64>("tauCommand", 1, &ImpedanceController::setCommandCB, this);
    
    return true;
  }

  void update(const ros::Time &time, const ros::Duration &period) 
  {

    // Send a torque command of 2 Nm to each joint
    std::vector<double> torque_command(joints_.size(), 0.0);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < joints_.size(); ++i) 
    {
        torque_command[i] = tauCommand[i];
        joints_[i].setCommand(torque_command[i]);
    }
   }


void setCommandCB(const std_msgs::Float64ConstPtr& msg)
  {
    if (msg->data.size() == tauCommand.size()) 
    {
          tauCommand = msg->data;
        } else {
          ROS_WARN("Received tauCommand message with incorrect size");
        }
  }

  void starting(const ros::Time &time) {}
  void stopping(const ros::Time &time) {}

};

PLUGINLIB_EXPORT_CLASS(panda_torque_control::ImpedanceController, controller_interface::ControllerBase);
} // namespace panda_torque_control
```

Comment: This already exists as the `JointEffortController` class. Please edit your question to explain what you need beyond the existing class. If you need something more, why are you not using the existing ros code as a starting point? The class doc is here: https://docs.ros.org/en/noetic/api/effort_controllers/html/namespaceeffort__controllers.html

Comment: As I'm quite new in Ros_control and gazebo, I'm going step by step but I have implemented in a real robot a torque control algorithm and I want to set up a simulation in gazebo using this same control that command a torque to every joint of the robot. Does JointEffortController allow me to control all joints together rather that one by one?

Comment: The link I provided already answers your question. Hint: in this context, "group" means multiple joints.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your implementation question, you can look at the existing `effort_controllers/ JointEffortController` to see what they did.

More generally, the functionality you want is already implemented by the `ros_control` subsystem. If you configure ros_control correctly, it will create a ".../command" topic that you can then use to move the arm.

Note that there is an inherent assumption that your particular arm *already* has a hardware_interface that accepts effort input (or none of these effort_controllers is going to work.)

Comment: thanks for the tip, yeah, I know that the functionality is already implemented already. I'm doing this because looking to the future, I will be writing an impedance control for two complete different robots that work together (a 7DOF panda and 6 DOF staubli). I'm not sure though if this is a good approach or should I use some existing code for that like panda_ros library, but thats another question I guess.